# Compiling Allegro 5 Program through command line on a Mac

Tags: c++, macos, command-line, g++, allegro5

I followed to steps to build and install Allegro 5 from their wiki (found here: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Main_Page) and seemingly succeeded with no problems.

allegro was installed to the following (as the wiki suggests) /usr/local/include and usr/local/lib and I have confirmed allegro is there.

I then wrote the following code in vim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

   if(!al_init())
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   display = al_create_display(640, 480);

   if(!display)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
   al_flip_display();
   al_rest(10.0);
   al_destroy_display(display);

   return 0;
}
```

I am new to using Unix and have only ever compiled c++ programs with g++ that were simple hello world files with no libraries needed.

Therefore after searching around on the internet I tried the following commands:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello `pkg-config --libs allegro-5`
```

resulting in the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
  implicit entry/start for main executable
  (maybe you meant: __al_mangled_main)
ld: symbols not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

BTW, I used homebrew to install dependencies instead of macports

brew install pkg-config
brew install zlib
etc...

It seems like a linking problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `$(pkg-config --libs allegro-5)` rather than `\`pkg-config --libs allegro-5\``

Comment: I just tried that and it results in the same error. I think it is something to do with things not being linked properly, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to compile with static libs or dynamic? and what is the output of the command: `pkg-config --libs allegro-5`

Comment: I am using static libs (at least I think I am. see here: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_GIT/OSX#Building_static_Allegro_with_make) "building static allegro with make"

output is: -L/usr/local/lib -lallegro

Comment: g++ hello.cpp -o hello `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5 allegro_main-5` - THIS WORKED. have no clue why.

Comment: Nice, put that as an answer and accept it. :) (must have been the `allegro_main-5` part that was key)?.

Answer (score 7):

try install allegro with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_pt-br.html) and use `gcc -o main main.c -lallegro -lallegro_main`

because the allegro_main is a compatibility library that allows the main function to work on all compilers. Required only from OS X.